# PHP print hex values of characters in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, hex, character

I want to print the hexadecimal values of each of the characters in a PHP string.  For example, I want to display the hex values of each character in a string where I'm trying to set the fourth character to Control-C (0x03).

```
$str=sprintf('ab1%c',0x03);
for ($cnt=0; $cnt<4; $cnt++)
{
    $chr=$str[$cnt];
    echo '$str['.$cnt.'] = "'.$str[$cnt].'" = '.sprintf('0x%02x',$chr[0])."\n";
}
var_dump(str_split($str));
```

What I get is this:

```
$str[0] = "a" = 0x00
$str[1] = "b" = 0x00
$str[2] = "1" = 0x01
$str[3] = "" = 0x00
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) ""
}
```

It seems that `$chr` is a *string* rather than a *character* and `sprintf()` is printing the integer value of a string - zero - instead of the integer value of a single character.

Is it possible to do this in PHP?  I was sure there's a way...

Comment: [ord()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you - you should have posted your comment as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @MarkBaker's comment, the solution is to use `ord()` to get the character's value:

```
$str=sprintf('ab1%c',0x03);
for ($cnt=0; $cnt<4; $cnt++)
{
    $chr=$str[$cnt];
    echo '$str['.$cnt.'] = "'.$str[$cnt].'" = '.sprintf('0x%02x',ord($chr))."\n";
}
var_dump(str_split($str));
```

yields the expected results:

```
$str[0] = "a" = 0x61
$str[1] = "b" = 0x62
$str[2] = "1" = 0x31
$str[3] = "" = 0x03
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have a char (character) type.  You are correct that you are getting a 1-character string as the result.